# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder' on Python 3.8 and Tensorflow 2.0 and Keras-Bert

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, python-3.8

I am getting this error on the line 273 even though I'm not using the placeholder in my code.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GA5.py", line 273, in <module>
  model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path,checkpoint_path,training=True,trainable=True,seq_len=SEQ_LEN)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_bert/loader.py", line 163, in load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
model, config = build_model_from_config(
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_bert/loader.py", line 46, in build_model_from_config
model = get_model(
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_bert/bert.py", line 85, in get_model
inputs = get_inputs(seq_len=seq_len)
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_bert/layers/inputs.py", line 12, in get_inputs
return [keras.layers.Input(
  File "/home/kosimadukwe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_bert/layers/inputs.py", line 12, in <listcomp>
return [keras.layers.Input(
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 175, in Input
input_layer = InputLayer(batch_input_shape=batch_shape,
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 84, in __init__
input_tensor = K.placeholder(shape=batch_input_shape,
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 517, in placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

I have searched similar errors and added these import lines as suggested

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

I am using Python3.8 and Tensorflow2.0 and Keras-bert. and from the tests ive done its most likely due to Keras-Bert.

Can anyone give me suggestions? I'm all out of options.

Comment: You are not using a version of Keras that supports TensorFlow 2.0, like Keras 2.3.1

Comment: I am using Keras 2.3.1

Comment: @Kosi  **I am using Python3.8** but Tensorflow supports Python up to version 3.7 as it's mentioned on [their page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: Can you provide the necessary reproducible information?

Comment: @TF_Support im not sure that's possible at the moment, i have uninstalled and installed so many things since this question was posted. If i recall correctly i was building an LSTM text classifier using Keras-bert library with python 3.8 and tensorflow 2.0. It seemed to be a compatibility issue as the Keras-bert library was not built with tf 2.0.